# How should I structure requests with side effects when using Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, webhooks

I'm using Django Rest Framework and it's integrated with an external service. I'm using an endpoint to receive a callback from a webhook whenever a new task is created in the external service.

When the callback request comes in, my code needs to create at least one object. But it's possible that multiple objects will need to be created from multiple different models. For example, if a new task is created it's possible that it was created by a new user, in which I also need to create a new user object to reflect this.

In total, there could be up to 5 additional objects made as side effects. I'm aware of multiple different places that this logic could be added (e.g. service layers, serializers, models, managers, views). But there seem to be issues with all of these.

Has anyone dealt with this issue before? If so, how did you solve it?

Comment: If new user was created, wouldn't you get webhook for that?

Comment: @Headmaster unfortunately, no. There are only webhooks for tasks :(

Answer (score 6):

First of all, it is important to understand the difference between an RPC-style API and a RESTful API. Simply put, you can imagine an RPC API to be "methods" that are "actions", while a RESTful API represents the state of your models.

For example, let's say we want to create an endpoint to handle user registration.

- A RPC style endpoint might be `/api/register`. A register function that might do X number of things.
- A REST style endpoint might be `/api/users`. Not an action, but simply just an endpoint that give us the state of the users that exist. A GET request would list the users and a POST request would create a new user.

With that said, it might be a bit more clear that in general, creating endpoints that do X number of actions might not be very "restful", and using a framework specifically named "Django **REST** Framework" might not be the right choice.

So in your particular case. I suggest that you avoid creating endpoints that work as methods, and instead treat them as the resources that they represent. This means that if you need to create a new user, you do a request to the user-endpoint, then if you need to create a new article with that user, you do a second request to the article-endpoint.

### Using Signals for Side Effects

I think if you do want side effects, they should be managed using signals. For example, let's say that you want to send out emails using a contact form. Instead of having a `/api/send_email` endpoint, you instead do a `/api/messages/` endpoint that represent a `Message` model, and then you use signals to send out emails whenever a new message is created.

By doing things this way, it still means that the API endpoint itself just represent the state of the model, while the side effect of modifying the state (sending a message on creation of a new message) is moved to the signal's responsibility.

Comment: Great explanation!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This is a helpful distinction. For most of the API endpoints I'm using a resource-based design (eg. `messages`). It's only for a couple of webhooks that I'm breaking away from that, because the request data is defined by the external service, which I don't control (it's a SaaS tool we integrate with).